# C++ comparing pointers to different types?

Tags: c++, generics, pointers, vector

I'm having a really hard time finding information about these kind of stuff! :(

I'm confused why this isn't working:

```
vector<B*> b;
vector<C*> c;
(B and C are subclasses of A) 
(both are also initialized and contain elements etc etc...) 

template <class First, class Second>
bool func(vector<First*>* vector1, vector<Second*>* vector2)
   return vector1 == vector2;
```

When compiling this returns:

```
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

I don't see why this wouldn't work, pointers hold addresses yeah? So why don't it just compare if the two vector pointers... point to the same address(-es)?

Comment: Pointers hold addresses in an implementation-defined manner. `reinterpret_cast<>` is free to change the actual numeric value based on the type.

Comment: Take a look at static cast and dynamic cast in c++

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? A pointer to one type of vector should never equal a pointer to another type of vector.  Maybe you could post some code using your `func` method.

Comment: @dunc123, I have it as a safety mechanism in case such a case: `func(b, b)´

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't think `reinterpret_cast<>` is allowed to change the numeric value based on the type. From the documentation: "The operation result is a simple binary copy of the value from one pointer to the other."

Comment: @Xaqq Thanks! I think I'm now going to look this up in the standard. Maybe I'm confusing this with some other cast operators? Like `static_cast<>`?

Comment: @H2CO3 Yeah I believe `static_cast<>` and `dynamic_cast<>` could change the value by adjusting the pointer so that it points to the right offset. Not sure though, would be interested to know what you find :)

Comment: If the compiler can see that the pointers types are unrelated, is it a valid optimization to just return false for this as due to the strict aliasing rules they can't point to the same thing. Or are there cases where it can? ( Imean if they are casted to void* or some such thing)

Comment: @jcoder If the pointer types are unrelated, it's not even valid for the compiler to accept the code, so there's nothing to optimize.

Comment: I mean with the casts to a void* ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simple example where what you're asking for won't work.

```
struct A{ int i; };
struct OhNoes { double d; };
struct B: public A {};
struct C: public OhNoes, public B {};
```

So here, B and C are both subclasses of A.
However, an instance of `C` is unlikely to have the same address as its `B` subobject.

That is, this:

```
C c;
B *b = &c; // valid upcast
assert(static_cast<void*>(b) == static_cast<void *>(&c));
```

will fail.

Comment: This is the problem OP will encounter if `First` and `Second` are the same type. if not, their problem is comparing pointers to two unrelated types.

Comment: @juanchopanza: The wording might not be the most precise, but he is right on the underlying issues: You cannot compare pointers *ignoring the type* (which is the question) as the comparison above will fail even though the objects are the same. +1

Comment: Actually, there might be a way for some types ... isn't `dynamic_cast<void*>` supposed to always find the most derived type address?

Comment: This means that, if I cast two pointers to the same type (and they both inherit from this type), the comparison works, independent of how the inheritance chain is built?

Do I understand this correctly?

Answer (score 4):

Your two vectors are different types and you cannot compare them.

If you want to check that you do not call func(b, b) then you can try:

```
template <typename T> bool func(vector<T> const & a, vector<T> const & b)
{
if (&a == &b) return false;
// do stuff
return true;
}
```

Unless you are doing something very strange then the pointers to two vectors of a different types will not be equal.  If you try and call func with two vectors of a different type then you will get a compiler error.

Comment: This template only features one type though, I'm in need of comparing vector pointers with (possibly) different types to check if they are not pointing to the same vector . Am I to understand that just isn't possible at all?

Comment: @optional: Perhaps you could write some code where this would be the case, i.e. two vector pointers with different types point to the same vector?

Comment: @optional: How could that happen? An object has a type, in a given location in memory there can be either an object of type T or an object of type U (or an unrelated object, or no object at all...) but there can never be an object of type T and an object of type U for unrelated types T and U (although it could be an object of a type that is both T and U (through inheritance, but that won't be the case in `std::vector`!)